# Python: Clear output console

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a loading progress bar, but I get something like this when I run my code:

```
[          ] 0%
[=         ] 10%
[==        ] 20%
[===       ] 30%
[====      ] 40%
[=====     ] 50%
[======    ] 60%
[=======   ] 70%
[========  ] 80%
[========= ] 90%
[==========] 100%
```

When I expected something like this:

```
[          ] 0%
<Later>
[=         ] 10%
<Even Later>
[==        ] 20%
<And you get the idea>
```

It's supposed to clear the previous line every time it prints a new one. I've tried everything I found on Google, but it wasn't much help. I tried using `"\r"`, but I get this:

```
[          ] 0%

[=         ] 10%

[==        ] 20%

[===       ] 30%

[====      ] 40%

[=====     ] 50%

[======    ] 60%

[=======   ] 70%

[========  ] 80%

[========= ] 90%

[==========] 100%
```

Here's my code:

```py
import time
import random
for p in range(0, 11):
   print("[" + ("="*p) + (" "*(10-p)) + "] " + str(p*10)+"%")
   time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 1))
```

Can someone help find a way to clear the whole output console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `end='\r'` as argument to `print` function:

```
print("[" + ("="*p) + (" "*(10-p)) + "] " + str(p*10)+"%", end='\r')
```

...which prints all your output in one line replacing the previous output.

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives me this: `[          ] 0%[=         ] 10%[==        ] 20%[===       ] 30%[====      ] 40%[=====     ] 50%[======    ] 60%[=======   ] 70%[========  ] 80%[========= ] 90%[==========] 100%`

Comment: It would run if you run this in CLI. Navigate to the directory your python file is and type `python yourfilename.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not working with Python notebook and '\r' is not working for you you can use the ASCII escape sequence

```
import time
import random
import sys
for p in range(0, 11):
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
    print("\r"+"[" + ("="*p) + (" "*(10-p)) + "] " + str(p*10)+"%")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 1))
```